# Azure DevOps YAML - .Net Core CLI can't pack using internal artifact feed

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, asp.net-core-cli

I'm trying to restore, build, pack and push in Azure DevOps with .Net Core CLI using YAML.

Restore has knowledge of the internal feed, however pack doesn't.

How can i add the internal feed to the pack operation?

```
parameters:
  projects: ''

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: "ProvisionRestoreProjects"
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '${{ parameters.projects }}'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: '/4d73414a-a21f-4f84-9355-90beadaf0a6e'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: "ProvisionBuildProjects"
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: ${{ parameters.projects }}
    arguments: '--configuration release  --no-cache'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: "ProvisionPackProjects" 
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    projects: ${{ parameters.projects }}
    versioningScheme: 'byEnvVar'
    versionEnvVar: 'NugetVersion'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: '/4d73414a-a21f-4f84-9355-90beadaf0a6e'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: "ProvisionPushProjects"
  inputs:
    command: 'push'
    packagesToPush: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.nupkg'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: '/4d73414a-a21f-4f84-9355-90beadaf0a6e'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify a feed in the `pack` command.

The `pack` command is only to pack the files to `.nupkg` file (NuGet package), then you push it to your feed.

More info about the command and which options can be used you can fine [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-pack?tabs=netcore2x).

Answer (score 2):

The `pack` command "[builds the project and creates NuGet packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-pack?tabs=netcore2x#description)", that's why it is trying to restore the packages again.

To prevent this, add `nobuild: true` to the task inputs:

```
- task: @DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Pack
  inputs:
    command: pack
    nobuild: true
```

It will no longer try to rebuild the project itself, but instead use the artifacts created in previous steps.